# Bootstrap: bring fixed horizontal nav bar above other elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a vertical bootstrap sidemenu that would responsively switch to horizontal.

The problem I have is that the sidemenu would hide behind other elements once it turns horizontal, see example in which the sidemenu would hide behind the text on small devices:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>

<body style = "padding-top:55px">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center text-left">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="position-fixed bg-dark">
          <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav overflow-auto flex-md-column flex-nowrap">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 123</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 123</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 123</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 123</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <h1>Some text</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>



    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

```
https://codepen.io/coffeeeecup/pen/ZEYpBJO
```

The reason for this behaviour is most likely position-fixed. But I need this attribute as the sidemenu should stay in a fixed position when scrolling.

How can I ensure that the elements would arrange below the submenu with position-fixed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Give `z-index: 1` for the position fixed element. and give a padding to the content according to height of fixed element.